# How to parse elasticsearch response in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, elasticsearch

I try to parse my elasticsearch response in php.
When i print my json resultat with a var_dump, i've got that:

```
Array (
    [took] => 6
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array (
        [total] => 5
        [successful] => 5
        [failed] => 0
    )
    [hits] => Array (
        [total] => 1
        [max_score] => 0.44896343
        [hits] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [_index] => car
                [_type] => car
                [_id] => DqE0c4ygRgC81o39DNmwhQ
                [_score] => 0.44896343
                [_source] => Array (
                    [currency] => EUR
                    [link] => myrurl
                    [reference] => A785454A
                    [brand] => mybrand
                    [model] => mymodel
                    [description] =>
                    [link_picture] => mylinkpicture
                    [price] => myprice
                    [km] => mykm
                    [start_years] =>
                    [active] => 1
                    [title] => mytitle
                    [ranking] => 22
                    [date_create] => 2014-05-26
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But, when i try to list or to find a title by a foreach:

```
$myData = json_decode($response);
foreach ($myobj->hits->hits as $result) {
    echo $result->_source->title;
}
```

that doesn't work, because i obtain this error:

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I don't see why.
Thanks in advnce.

Comment: First you are calling it `$myData` , later you try to use `$myobj`. Could that be your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In foreach you are trying to use "$myobj". 
But decoded json is in "$myData".